# BIngbot on my network IP

Tags: logging, apache2

I was looking my apache logs and I find out this.

```
192.168.1.2 - - [30/Nov/2016:15:46:52 +0100] "GET http://www.Mywebsite.... HTTP/1.1" 200 5539 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
```

This happen a few times with that IP, but I cannot understand how is bingbot executing from that IP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's *that* IP?

Comment: Is the IP actually 192.168.1.2? So it is not even a public facing server?

Comment: 192.168.1.2 is your gateway, and your gateway strip out the source IP.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your local IP, then look at the mod_log_config.conf and check the 
first Format string is %v or %h -look at Custom Log Formats here 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html-.
 But if this is not the 
case, then it is a forged ip address and the bing bot is a fake bot.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything between the internetz and your apache server?

If not, maybe you are seeing like the X-Forwarded-For IP (assuming MS/Bing would be using a proxy on their end). In which case, as @Talal suggests, consider re-checking your logging.